# Altium Designer - Delete a single Datum in a Datum Dimension

Tags: altium

I have an extra Datum in a Datum Dimension that I am using. I want to delete it, but when I try to select it, I end up selecting the entire Datum Dimension. Is there a method to individually select a single Datum so that I can delete it?

Comment: Are you in the PCB editor or in Draftsman?

Comment: I am in PCB editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shicon Wen, sorry, this is not possible. Many users have encountered the same behaviour so you are not alone. No idea if this has been addressed in upcoming AD 18 release.

Comment: Thank you for the closure. I also found that you can "remove" a single Datum by dragging it on top of another Datum so that it "disappears".